# Find word with mistakes in string

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say you need to check a string line for word "monster".
You have example string lines like this:

```
1) People are afraid of monters
2) Mansters are very scary
3) I like mnsters
```

As you can see all "monster" words are spelled wrongly. 
The question is how u can find out that those strings contain "monster"?
I was thinking about somekind **for loop with length of word**, which will make different manipulations with word "monster", like deleting 1st or last letter("onster","monste"), letter in middle("monter"), separating word in 2 parts("mon","ster") or smth like that. And then trying to find this new word in string.

You can say - Use regular expressions! - but I guess I can`t use them when my word -"monster" is dynamically entered data.

Thank you for all your answers.

Additional question :

1. Flowers grow in **mystery** cave.
   Entered word - myst.
   LastIndexOf will be my choice? or should i use smthing like  string.search(/myst/gi)?

Indexof("myst") and string.search(new RegExp("myst","gi") will return same result in this case, but i assume that 2nd option takes more time doing that.

Comment: what exactly you want to do? to check whether the word monster is in the string or some thing else?

Comment: You could use a brute-force approach such as you suggest if you're just looking for the word 'monsters'. I can't see that being very useful. Presumably you really want a dictionary lookup?

Comment: There are a few useful algorythms, e.g. Levenshtein Distance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Birlla, as i would like to find out does static data(contains 500+ sentences in doc,need to check each one) contain dinamycally entered data. I showed it in example...Lets say user entered "car","monster",oil" and he want to know which lines contain those words, but don`t forget that they can be spelled wrongly, as i stated in question

Comment: Mike W, as is said entered data - dynamicall, so i guess i ll try something like for(int i=0, i=word.length , i++) and make somekind of manipulations inside... Thank u for answer.

Comment: @Birlla just new to stack:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a javascript implementation of the levenshteinDistance algorithm which gives you a measure of how different two sequences of characters are.  In this example, I compare each word in a series of test source strings to a particular candidate word.  There are many ways to extend this further such as understanding plural forms and not discounting a match that only diffs in plurality.  Anyway, here's the implementation with a [link to a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3xEwj/) below:

```
function levenshteinDistance (s, t) {
        if (!s.length) return t.length;
        if (!t.length) return s.length;

        return Math.min(
                levenshteinDistance(s.substr(1), t) + 1,
                levenshteinDistance(t.substr(1), s) + 1,
                levenshteinDistance(s.substr(1), t.substr(1)) + (s.charAt(0).toLowerCase() !== t.charAt(0).toLowerCase() ? 1 : 0)
        );
}

var testStrings = [
    "People are afraid of monters.",
    "Mansters are very scary, even in the daytime",
    "I like mnsters.",
    "I like a big, scary monser"
];

var candidateWord = "monsters";
var words;
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < testStrings.length; i++) {
    words = testStrings[i].split(/[\s.,<>;:'"{}\[\]]+/);
    for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        if (words[j]) {
            results.push({word: words[j], score: levenshteinDistance(words[j], candidateWord)});
        }
    }
}
```

And, a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3xEwj/

After sorting the output, it shows these scores for each of the words in the test string (lower score means smaller difference, so better match):

```
Score: 1
    monters
    Mansters
    mnsters
Score: 2
    monser
Score: 6
    scary
    very
    scary
Score: 7
    People
    of
    even
    in
    are
    daytime
    like
    like
    are
    the
Score: 8
    I
    I
    a
    big
    afraid
```

You can package up this logic however you want.  You can set a threshold for how much difference you are willing to tolerate and then just use that threshold as a binary match.  For example, you could set your threshold at `2` so that any score less than or equal to `2` means it's a match.

Comment: I ll vote it up cause as i said earlier , i found it very interesting, great solution and information for such task;)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to spell correct your sentences.

For this you need to have a dictionary. The spell correction part is bit tricky but can be implemented. For each word in the dictionary, you need to find the nearest match in the dictionary. I know of a technique which computes [Levenstien Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) with each word in the dictionary, and for a word in the string, if it is not 0, then it is a misspelled word. In that case you need to correct it to the nearest match. For 'monter', its minimum distance would be 1 with 'monster', hence correct word would be monster. In this way you correct the entire sentence. So now there are no misspelled words.

So if your input is

```
1) People are afraid of monters
2) Mansters are very scary
3) I like mnsters
```

Your output after spell correction would be

```
1) People are afraid of monsters
2) Monsters are very scary
3) I like monsters
```

Basically there should be no 'out of dictionary' words after this step.
I had implemented a slightly modified version of it, you can go through it at [github](https://github.com/anooprh/SpeechToText/tree/master/A-2), but I hope you get the idea.

After this, you can count the occurrences of word 'monster' and you would get the required count you need. Or you can filter out the strings with word 'monster' in them.
Correct me if my understanding is not correct or this is not what you are trying to implement.

Comment: Thank you,Anoop, for your answer, but there is no chance to have a prepared dictionary beforehand) That too much for such task:) Anyway, thank u.